# Difficulty using sentiment analysis with chrome extension: Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to determine the sentiment score of certain words. I'm having trouble using the dictionary below to analyse the words extracted. The dictionary is usually 3000 + words but for testing it is much less.

I have 2 files in my program, index.js

```
 //index.js

    const afinn165 = {
    abandon: -2,
    abandoned: -2,
    abandons: -2,
    abducted: -2,
    abduction: -2,
    abductions: -2,
    abhor: -3,
    abhorred: -3,
  };

  async function scrapeTextAndAnalyzeSentiment() {

    console.log("TESTING");
    try {
        console.log("SENTIMENT ANALYSIS = " + afinn165.abandons); //should give -2
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error while accessing sentiment value:", error);
    }
}

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
    if (changeInfo.status === "complete" && tab.active) {
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            target: { tabId: tabId },
            function: scrapeTextAndAnalyzeSentiment,
        })
        .then(()=> {
            console.log("Injected scrapeTextAndAnalyzeSentiment");
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
});
```

and manifest.json

```
{
"name": "App Name",
"short_name": "App",
"description": "Provides sentiment analysis on text content of screen",
"homepage_url": "http://chrome.google.com/webstore",
"version": "0.0.1",
"version_name": "0.0.1",
"manifest_version": 3,
"minimum_chrome_version": "88",
"permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "scripting"
],
"host_permissions": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*", "https://esm.sh/afinn-165@2"],

"background": {
    "service_worker": "index.js"
},
"action": {
    "default_title": "__MSG_appName__"
}
```

}

I'm currently getting this error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: scrapeTextAndAnalyzeSentiment is not defined
at <anonymous>:1:16
at <anonymous>:1:56
```

The 'Testing' message does appear on the console

Any suggestions would be great.